# Skip Login Process In Functional Tests

Tags: django, selenium, testing, tdd

I am using allauth and have began making some functional tests. I have tested the login function and now am wanting to test other things, but I cant find a way to begin my functional tests with a pre-authenticated user. I have tried using the following code but I cant manage to get a user logged in automatically.

```
def create_pre_authenticated_session(self, username, email):
        session_key = create_pre_authenticated_session(username, email)

        # to set a cookie we need to first visit the domain
        self.browser.get(self.live_server_url + "/")
        self.browser.add_cookie(dict(
            name=settings.SESSION_COOKIE_NAME,
            value=session_key,
            path='/',
        ))
```

```
def create_pre_authenticated_session(username, email):
    user = User.objects.create(username=username, email=email)
    session = SessionStore()
    session[SESSION_KEY] = user.pk
    session[BACKEND_SESSION_KEY] = settings.AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS[0]
    session.save()
    return session.session_key
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [force_login](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/testing/tools/#django.test.Client.force_login) method to login user

> If your site uses Django’s authentication system, you can use the
>   force_login() method to simulate the effect of a user logging into the
>   site. Use this method instead of login() when a test requires a user
>   be logged in and the details of how a user logged in aren’t important.
>
> Unlike login(), this method skips the authentication and verification
>   steps: inactive users (is_active=False) are permitted to login and the
>   user’s credentials don’t need to be provided.

```
self.client.force_login(user)
```

---

```
Add the cookie to browser afterwards

cookie = self.client.cookies['sessionid']
self.browser.add_cookie({'name': 'sessionid', 'value': cookie.value, 'secure': False, 'path': '/'})
self.browser.refresh()
```

Comment: Thank you. This works perfectly in my unit tests but not in my functional tests

Comment: Unit tests are subcategory of functional tests, i haven't noticed you are using selenium browser in speed pass through your question

Comment: Thank you so much. I spent a lot of the morning messing around trying to get a cookie set but couldnt get it to work and eventually figured it was wrong. Really appreciate it.